# Opening apps installed in WSL Ubuntu 22.04 in Windows 11

Tags: command-line, virtualbox, icons, windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-11

I just finished installing Ubuntu 22.04 in Windows 11 via Microsoft store. Once I click to open Ubuntu after install it opens in cmd, now I've installed other applications through cmd like VirtualBox.

The question is, how do I open the application I've installed from Windows shell as an icon?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  There is some confusing terminology that you are using in your question, and I'm not quite sure what you mean.  "cmd" is the old Windows DOS-compatible shell, so I don't think that's what you mean - Do you mean, *"installed other applications in the Ubuntu shell ..."*?  Also, not clear what you mean by *"application I've installed from the Windows shell"* - Also, how did you install VirtualBox?  Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1457647/edit) your question to add clarity.  Any commands you used and output you received could be useful.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

i think you should pay attention to ths description and key features of the WSL(Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS) in Microsoft store:

> a complete ***Ubuntu terminal environment*** in minutes with Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL).

**Ubuntu desktop** provides a complete desktop experience with a graphical user interface, pre-installed applications, and a wide range of software packages for various purposes. Ubuntu desktop is designed to be a standalone system and does not require Windows to run.

On the other hand, **WSL** provides a command-line interface to access a Linux shell and run Linux applications. WSL is not a complete operating system but rather a subsystem that runs on top of Windows.

- WSL is a compatibility layer for running Linux command-line tools and utilities directly on Windows.
- WSL integrates with Windows and allows users to access Windows files from Linux and vice versa
- Also, you can install ubuntu on wsl on win11, here's [the tutorial](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-on-wsl2-on-windows-11-with-gui-support#1-overview)

So i mean WSL and ubuntu are completely different (albeit somewhat related) things. And that's the reason why there are not ubuntu app icons on windows